# Working with SQLServer 2008, stored procedures and WebService

Tags: java, web-services, stored-procedures, netbeans, sql-server-2008-r2

So I'm trying to invoke an stored procedure from a web service but as soon as I add either the "prepareCall" or the "prepareStatement" my WebService stops working. When I test it it shows some big big error

> > Service invocation threw an exception with message : null; Refer to the server log for more details

and then

> > Exceptions details : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Followed by this

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at org.glassfish.webservices.monitoring.WebServiceTesterServlet.doPost(WebServiceTesterServlet.java:330) at org.glassfish.webservices.monitoring.WebServiceTesterServlet.invoke(WebServiceTesterServlet.java:106) at org.glassfish.webservices.JAXWSServlet.doPost(JAXWSServlet.java:133) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:688) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161) at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331) at `enter code here`org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231) at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317) at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195) at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860) at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757) at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056) at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229) at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137) at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104) at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90) at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79) at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54) at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59) at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71) at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532) at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) at org.glassfish.webservices.monitoring.WebServiceTesterServlet.doPost(WebServiceTesterServlet.java:301) ... 28 more Caused by: com.sun.xml.ws.fault.ServerSOAPFaultException: Client received SOAP Fault from server: java.lang.NullPointerException Please see the server log to find more detail regarding exact cuase of the failure. at com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAP11Fault.getProtocolException(SOAP11Fault.java:193) at com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:126) at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.StubHandler.readResponse(StubHandler.java:247) at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.deserializeResponse(DatabindingImpl.java:177) at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.deserializeResponse(DatabindingImpl.java:256) at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:128) at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:102) at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:151) at $Proxy262.hello(Unknown Source) ... 33 more
```

Currently all my WS does is this:

```
SQL sql = new SQL("{call dbo.iniciarSesion(?,?)}", "");
```

The SQL class looks like this:

```
public SQL(String ruta) {
    try {
        this.con = new ConexionDB(ruta);
        this.ps = this.con.getConBD().prepareCall("");
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SQL.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

I noticed that if I add the Exception is way worse than having just the try and catch. If I test my code outside the WebService it works just fine.

Please, help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe stored procedures do not return anything function does. So make sure you have a function in your database, which returns the desired result. Then try to use that result for creating the proper response for your web service.